# What is the difference between Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN) and Generative Antagonistic System (GAS)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, artificial-intelligence, gan

What is the difference between Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN) and 
Generative Antagonistic System (GAS) in the neural network?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure "generative antagonistic system" isn't actually a thing, as a google search for the exact phrase only yielded a handful of results, all dated 2018, and all in reference to GANs. In fact this question is the top result. All of the other results were from some sort of news article without any technical content. I think someone just made up the term and it got copied a few times.